# Manage Lotus Domino mail with SugarCRM

Tags: smtp, imap, ibm-domino, sugarcrm

anyone knows how configure SugarCRM (standard IMAP I suppose) with Lotus Domino 8.5?

I have it configured, SMTP mail test works fine, but folders doesn't appear except INBOX (I'm using standard IMAP folder names). And when I try to open an e-mail then I get an Internal Server Error message.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get folders fron a Lotus Domino Mail- database this database has to be IMAP- enabled and the IMAP- Task has to be loaded on that server. If you are not the administrator of the Domino Server, then you have to ask the admin, to do the conversion and activation for you.

All necessary steps are documented in the domino admin- help, that is on the domino server and can be found online multiple times [for example here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_MODIFYING_MAIL_FILES_TO_SUPPORT_IMAP.html)

Comment: Okay, I'm the new (and noob) admin of the Domino Server, I'll take a look at the info. Thanks